# events are not working when 10 tcp clients are connected

Tags: c#, tcp, barcode-scanner

I am using custom client connection for 10 tcp clients.

```
bool _flagScanner1Connect = true;
private xyzTranmissionProtocol  xyz1TranmissionProtocol = null;
private static readonly object LockWhileConnectingForScanner1 = new object();
internal ICustomClient Scanner1Conn;
System.Threading.Timer _tmrCheck1ClientConn;

public void Start1ScannerConn()
{
    try
    {
        _tmrCheck1ClientConn = new System.Threading.Timer(Check1ScannerConn, null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    }
    catch (Exception )
    {

    }
}

private void Check1ScannerConn(object state)
{
    if (!_flagScanner1Connect)
        return;
    lock (LockWhileConnectingForScanner1)
    {
        if (Scanner1Conn == null || Scanner1Conn.CommunicationState == ClientCommunicationStates.Disconnected)
        {
            try
            {
                _tmrCheck1ClientConn.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);

             Scanner1Conn = CustomClientFactory.CreateClient(new CustomClientTcpEndPoint(“Scanner IpAdress”, “Scanner Port Number”));
             Scanner1Conn.Connected += Scanner1Conn_Connected; ;
             Scanner1Conn.Disconnected += Scanner1Conn_Disconnected;
             Scanner1Conn.MessageReceived += Scanner1Conn_MessageReceived;
             xyz1TranmissionProtocol = new xyzTranmissionProtocol();
             Scanner1Conn.TransmissionProtocol = xyz1TranmissionProtocol;
             .Connect();
             //SEND A PING MESSAGE
             _tmrCheck1ClientConn.Change(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));



                    }
                    catch (Exception )
                    {
                        if (_flagScanner1Connect)

                        try
                        {
                            Scanner1Conn?.Disconnect();
                        }
                        catch { }
                        try
                        {
                            Scanner1Conn?.Dispose();
                        }
                        catch { }
                        try
                        {
                            Scanner1Conn = null;
                        }
                        catch { }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        _tmrCheckClientConn.Change(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

i have written 10 diffrent fuctions for 10 barcode scanners. if i use 3 or less than 3 my application will work. but if i use more than 3 scanners then messagerecived events are not fired. and the application will become very slow.
can anyone help me out to solve this issue.

Comment: is this code instanced per barcode reader? it looks like potentially you are trying to do this all on the UI thread but this isnt a minimal complete viable example to truly tell where and what are the issues, you need to debug this

Comment: Events work. With so many `catch{}` blocks though you'll never know when or why your code throws exceptions. It looks like you run into concurrency issues right from the start and tried to cover them up with locking, hiding exceptions and ignoring disposed objects. The problems though remain

Comment: above code is for 1 scanner.i have written 10 times for different scanners with different parameter.

Comment: @sudhaka remove all `catch{}` blocsk, all `?.Disconnect()`, `?.Dispose()` calls and fix the original concurrency issues. If you can't get that code to work for 1 or 2 scanners it won't work for 10.

Comment: above code is working for maximum 3 scanners. but if i connect more than 3 scanners, it will get connect. but after triggering i am not receiving value. but if trigger 3 or less than that then it will work perfectly

Comment: @subhaka for example, *don't* global state and instances, like that single `Scanner1Conn` instance for all clients. This guarantees you'll run into concurrency issues. After all, each time the timer fires you create a *new* instance. Why store it in a *field*?

Comment: @sudhakar no, it's not working. If it did, you wouldn't have to cover up exceptions like this.

Comment: @sudhakar btw by connecting event handlers to the *field* instead of the instance you create you ensure that if something goes wrong, there may be an invalid `Scanner1Conn` instance with no event handlers attached. What is this code supposed to do? Why is it inside a *timer*?

Comment: private void Check1ScannerConn(object state), private void Check2ScannerConn(object state),  private void Check3ScannerConn(object state) like this i have written functions. if i trigger any 3 then it will work . but if i trigger more than that it is not working

Comment: Why are you connecting and disconnecting after each message? How can you tell which scanner you are responding to?  You should be use async TCP method.

Comment: @sudhakar it looks like the code is trying to do two completely different things - create a `ICustomClient` instance **and** check if that instance failed for any reason with a watchdog timer. The end result is that it does neither. Create a *separate* method that creates a new instance, *fully* configures it (ie adds the event handlers) and returns it. That means, no fields. Then, in the watchdog timer, check the active instance, *close and dispose of it* if it's failed and then replace it with a new instance created by the function.

Comment: the long and short is: this is a mess.. a big mess, one a bit big for SO

Comment: In any case *don't* hide exceptions. They are the only way you can know if your code actually runs.

Comment: i am using 10 threading.timers in my code with different functions like Check1ScannerConn, Check2ScannerConn etc

Comment: timers do not run t hings on different threads... you are still using the UI thread for all this mess

Comment: @sudhakar this needs full rewriting. If you have multiple scanners, *don't* create a different field and different code for each one. Create a *separate* class that contains the connection class and the event handlers. If you want 10 clients, create 10 instances of these and put them into an array. Don't try to any business logic in those instances though. The event handlers should do nothing more than post messages to eg a ConcurrentQueue or ActionBlock<T> for processing.